# How can I syntax check (not render) a Rails 3 ERB template file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I'm trying to have a git pre-commit hook perform a syntax check on all Ruby code; there is one on GitHub at https://github.com/cypher/git-ruby-syntax-check.

It attempts to check .erb files by `erb -x` to translate them into Ruby code and then passes the output to `ruby -c` for syntax checking. Unfortunately, Rails 3 introduced a custom ERB parser that is [incompatible](http://timelessrepo.com/block-helpers-in-rails3) with Ruby's standard ERB, and so the pre-commit hook is finding errors where there are none.

Is there some equivalent to `erb -x` that will output Ruby code from a Rails 3 ERB file?

Comment: If you test all of your view, you don't need this check validation.

Comment: @shingara I disagree. This *is* a way to test your view, in a way other tests can't. Invalid markup may pass your functional tests because the browser "fixes" it for you, but still leave subtle bugs, or cause future problems, since no test is 100% comprehensive.

Comment: @shingara Or perhaps you were saying "validate after rendering, not before" rather than "don't validate at all"? In which case I see your point (and I could see an argument either way :-)

Comment: This is useful. It this could be used a really quick sanity check, in additional to more comprehensive functional tests.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have not dug much into either of these but you might try [rails-erb-check](http://rubygems.org/gems/rails-erb-check) ([Git project](https://github.com/jugyo/rails-erb-check)) or this [blog entry](http://diaspunk.blogspot.com/2011/01/rake-task-to-syntax-check-erb-haml-rb.html). I agree with shingara but the Blog Post describes a situation where this is useful and I wonder if you are in a similar position:

> Diaspora is pretty fluid right now. This means we are have some green
>   tests, some missing tests, and other tests that check intent (not
>   implementation). In an ideal world, I suppose test cases would cover
>   all of our bases...
>
> Until then, I've added a new task to my fork, check_syntax:all. This
>   breaks down further to the subtasks check_syntax:erb,
>   check_syntax:haml, check_syntax:haml_ruby, check_syntax:sass, and
>   check_syntax:yaml.

Answer (score 2):

If you get an "argument list too long error" for rails-erb-check , you can try [rails-erb-lint](https://github.com/katgironpe/rails-erb-lint) which scans your current views folder.

Comment: this tool makes a lot of sense compared to the accepted answers as this provides a functionality to scan a whole folder rather than scanning a single file at once.

Comment: It is well maintained. There are at least two of us managing the project. No matter how tiny it is, it will always work.

Comment: I get the following error when running this: `private method `desc' called for main:Object`. No matter which directory I was in and which options I passed it. On Rails 5.2.